# Abstract classes in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, abstract-class

I am trying to use Abstract Base Classes in Python 2.5 (http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html). However, this feature is new in Python 2.6. Can I just copy the source file `abc.py` into my pythonpath and have everything work properly? If not, how else would I get abstract base classes in Python 2.5?

Comment: Why on earth are you using Python 2.5? Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 2.5 - backwards compatibility with a library that is no longer being updated. I'm not really sure why it doesn't work with newer version of Python, but it doesn't.

Comment: Which one? There might be an alterantive.

Comment: I'm using pyspeech for speech recognition and TTS on Windows 7

Comment: How about [Dragonfly](http://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the [*abc.py* module from Python2.6](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Lib/abc.py).  It has no dependencies and does not use any features specific to Python 2.6.

The [Python 2.7 source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/abc.py) is more complicated with a dependency on WeakRefSet.

In addition to copying *abc.py*, you may what to create versions of *isinstance* and *issubclass* functions that are abc-aware.

Comment: I tried this, but I can instantiate abstract base classes without overriding the abstract methods and properties. I am using ABCMeta exactly as it is used in the example. I am simply running the code found in the comments of the abc.py file (the link you gave me). Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Validation isn't built-in to the ABCs.  You have to add that yourself.

Comment: @Ord: Are you using new-style classes? Also, it's more than likely that you don't need ABCs.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what new-style classes are... could you point me to somewhere I can learn about them? Do I need to use new-style classes to make use of ABCs? And why wouldn't I need ABCs?